# Unable to launch Jupyter with Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I have updated to windows 11 recently. so I had to install anaconda navigators again but when I tried to launch jupyter Notebook it pops me an error. The error is as below. Please help me with the solution.
error-
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 44, in
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2_init_.py", line 12, in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmzcI.png)
from .environment import Environment
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in
from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in
from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in
from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\markupsafe_init_.py)**

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the markupsafe package in the enviroment terminal of the Anaconda Navigator

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Comment: hello thanks tried this but it did not work